# forceNetwork in R

Tags: html, r, perl, networkd3

I have called the following and it makes an HTML file with networkD3 perfectly.

```
forceNetwork(Links=g2$links, Nodes=g2$nodes, Source='source', Target='target', NodeID='name', Group='group', opacityNoHover=TRUE, Nodesize='group',height = 1000, width = 1000, fontSize = 20,linkDistance=200,clickAction = mcs2, zoom=TRUE)  %>% saveNetwork(file = "test-network.html")
```

However in the created HTML it sets the `fill` parameter for the browser and viewer to be `false`.

```
<script type="application/htmlwidget-sizing" data-for="htmlwidget-18644f4e905f10bd8c40">
    {"viewer":{"width":1300,"height":1300,"padding":10,"fill":false},"browser":{"width":1300,"height":1300,"padding":10,"fill":false}}
</script>
```

The above is from the generated HTML file and is the final `<script>` tag that is generated from the `saveNetwork` call.

How can I change the `fill` and `padding` values from R before calling `saveNetwork` in R through perl? Below is the code that does not produce the desired effects.

```
$r->run(q`fn <- fn <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source", 
               Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
               Group = "group", opacity = 0.4, zoom = TRUE)`);
$r -> run(q`fn$sizingPolicy$viewer$fill <- TRUE`);
$r -> run(q`fn$sizingPolicy$browser$fill <- TRUE`);
$r -> run(q`saveNetwork(fn, file = "test-network.html", selfcontained=TRUE)`);
```

However this still outputs the fill parameter with "false".

Comment: Basically you have to not set the "height" and "weight" parameters , then save the network - this works!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

fn <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source", 
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   Group = "group", opacity = 0.4, zoom = TRUE)

fn$sizingPolicy$viewer$fill <- TRUE
fn$sizingPolicy$browser$fill <- TRUE

fn$sizingPolicy$viewer$padding <- 20
fn$sizingPolicy$browser$padding <- 20

saveNetwork(fn, "forceNetwork.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
```

Comment: Solution from R-side, executing this from perl does not work - same issue different mode of execution

Comment: What does this have to do with Perl?

Comment: The problem was setting the browser and viewer in R from PERL... using Statistics::R..... your solution is perfect from an R perspective

Comment: oh... you must have changed the question/target after I wrote my answer

Comment: maybe you should run a list of all the R commands in one run() command? or write the R commands into a file and use run_from_file()?

Comment: Setting the height and width parameters in the forcedNetwork call caused the issue - without these then the fill properties seems to work for me

Answer (score -1):

A quick search reveals that the `htmlwidgets` package provides `sizingPolicy` which allows you to adjust the required parameters

Something like this

```
sizingPolicy(padding = 0, browser.fill = TRUE)
```